# RESTEASY How to get @PathParam to match a UUID?

Tags: java, ajax, rest, jboss, resteasy

I'm using RESTEasy and Jboss eap 6.1.

I have the following resource:

```
@Path("/sessions")
public class Sessions {
    @DELETE
    @Path("/{sessionId}/")
    public Response logout(@PathParam("sessionId") String sessionId)
    {
        //sessions.remove(sessionId);

        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

`sessionId` is a generated UUID which has the form like `9b3db022-84de-4ba2-8194-5ff7542bf86b`

I made the following call from the client:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/sessions/" + javaRest.cookie.get("sessionId") + "/",
    type: "DELETE",             
    success : //do something,
    error : //do something;
    )}
```

`javaRest.cookie.get(cookieName)` is a function to find the value of the given `cookieName`.

But I got the following response error header:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden,
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1,
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8,
Content-Length: 1072,
Date: Mon, 01 Jul 2013 17:22:48 GMT
```

Then I made another `@GET` with the same setup as the `@DELETE` resource. However, this time the response header is 404 Not Found instead of 403.

I'm doubting it has something to do with the format of the UUID (which has various "-" in between). If it is, how could I fix this?

Comment: Maybe I should also mention that an ajax call to `url: "sessions"` with `type: "POST"` works just perfect. The problem only arise for any resource `@Path` inside the class.

Comment: Apparently, I found the answer for my question, I will post details in the next 8 hours (reputation restriction.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. This is a small but very vital mistake on my part.

I wrote on the question that I used:

```
$.ajax({
url: "sessions/" + javaRest.cookie.get("sessionId") + "/",
type: "DELETE",             
success : //do something,
error : //do something;
)}
```

But I myself did not type in exactly what I typed here.

Instead of using `sessions/` , I used `/sessions/` in my client code. Ajax resolves `/sessions/` differently than `sessions/` in a way that break the application.

When the application is deployed on JBoss server, its URL is something like `http://localhost:8080/AppName/`

with `sessions/`, ajax resolve the URL to `http://localhost:8080/AppName/sessions/`.
However, with `/sessions/`, the URL is resolved to `http://localhost:8080/sessions/` and break the application.

I guess I made a fool out of myself here. But I want to thank Wilker Iceri for your fast response.

The decision to keep or to delete this question is entirely up to the staff.

Answer (score 0):

You can try encode your param in js with `encodeURIComponent(param);`

Comment: I tried to change `url: "sessions/" + javaRest.cookie.get("sessionId") + "/"` to `url: "sessions/" + encodeURIComponent(javaRest.cookie.get("sessionId")) + "/"` but the problem still persist. Am I getting your suggestion wrong?

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. It was a mistake on my part. I will post the detailed answer after 8 hours (reputation restriction)